# Inject not working as expected

Tags: ruby, inject

Can anybody explain why these two snippets of code are not equivalent? Either I am missing something or inject does not do what I think it does. Given:

```
nodes = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
```

This code:

```
result = Hash.new
nodes.each do |node|
  result[node[:id]] = node.inspect
end
result
```

returns

```
 {
  1 => "{:id=>1}",
  2 => "{:id=>2}"
}
```

But this:

```
nodes.inject({}) {|hash, node|hash[node[:id]] = node.inspect}
```

returns:

```
"{:id=>2}"
```

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> inject not working as expected

Well, your expectations are wrong. :)

Block to `inject`/`reduce` should return the new value of the accumulator.

```
nodes = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
res = nodes.inject({}) {|hash, node| hash[node[:id]] = node.inspect; hash}
res # => {1=>"{:id=>1}", 2=>"{:id=>2}"}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's getting late, knew I was being thick!